# Hyperlink in Excel to a cell to another sheet in same workbook

Tags: excel

I want to be able to click on a cell with an employee ID and when clicked it hyperlinks to the cell on the 2nd sheet in the same workbook with the same employee ID.

I cannot figure it out...any help is appreciated.

I've tried this...`=IF(J2=YES,(HYPERLINK("[us_aiSV2.XLSX!SHEET2]B:B"&MAT‌​CH(Sheet1!D:D,0))),"‌​")`

Comment: What have you tried so far? Hint: use the macro recorder to get the basic framework of creating a hyperlink, then modify that code as part of an event procedure.

Comment: The hyperlink function will work to link to cell. If you just add the range on the second parameter it should work. Are you trying to add automation so that it searches for the same ID in the second sheet?

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to add automation where is searches for the same ID in the second sheet...

Comment: I've tried this...=IF(J2=YES,(HYPERLINK("[us_aiSV2.XLSX!SHEET2]B:B"&MATCH(Sheet1!D:D,0))),"")

Comment: That doesn't work either...I receive a #NAME? error

Comment: The `#Name?` is caused by the missing quotes around YES. Read my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Let me point to some mistakes in your formula:

- Unless there is a [named range](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Define-and-use-names-in-formulas-4d0f13ac-53b7-422e-afd2-abd7ff379c64) called "Yes", you need to put the text into double quotes
- The range you construct for the [hyperlink](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/HYPERLINK-function-333c7ce6-c5ae-4164-9c47-7de9b76f577f) does not work.
- The workbook brackets `[` and `]` are not in the right position. They should be placed **around the file name with extension**.
- The exclamation mark `!` needs to go **after the sheet name**, not before.
- You can't append a row number to a whole column reference. E.g. `B:B"&20`
- The [Match function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/MATCH-function-e8dffd45-c762-47d6-bf89-533f4a37673a) is **missing the lookup_value argument**.

Try along these lines:

```
=HYPERLINK("[Book1.xlsx]Sheet2!A"&MATCH(A1,Sheet2!A:A,0),"test")
```

Translated to your formula:

```
=IF(J2="YES",HYPERLINK("[us_aiSV2.XLSX]SHEET2!B"&MAT‌​CH(A2,Sheet1!D:D,0),"text to click"),"‌​")
```

I don't know in which cell your Employee ID lives. I've used A2. Adjust to suit.